# Reuse HTML but bind different model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm using AngularJS in my website. One page on my site is quite large, as in, it has a lot of HTML elements. Imagine something like this:

```
<div id="bronze">
  <input ng-model="league.bronze.name">
  <input ng-model="league.bronze.title">
  <input ng-model="league.bronze.description">
  ... about 15 more inputs ...
  <input ng-model="league.bronze.color1">
  <input ng-model="league.bronze.color2">
</div>
<div id="silver">
  <input ng-model="league.silver.name">
  <input ng-model="league.silver.title">
  <input ng-model="league.silver.description">
  ... about 15 more inputs ...
  <input ng-model="league.silver.color1">
  <input ng-model="league.silver.color2">
</div>
```

I also have `gold` and `platinum`. A site admin must fill in all these settings. This is not a problem for him. But it is for me as a developer.

Everytime I add one or more elements to the "bronze" section then I also have to do the same for every other section. The only difference is the `ng-model` value.

Isn't there a smarter way to do this? Because right now I'm kinda repeating my self everytime an element needs to be added...

Comment: have you tried using ng-repeat?

Comment: or you can consider writing the directive for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller do:

```
$scope.types = ['gold', 'silver', 'bronze'];
$scope.properties = ['name', 'title', 'description'];
```

And in your html do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="myType in types" id="{{myType}}">
  <input ng-repeat="myProperty in properties" ng-model="league[myType][myProperty]">
</div>
```

### [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cd2ruky4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this quick example of using ng-repeat for input fields

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wa1mbuDllqnlikmbQXp4?p=preview)

in your case it will be something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="league in leagues>
        <input ng-model="league.bronze.name">
  <input ng-model="league.title">
  <input ng-model="league.description">
  ... about 15 more inputs ...
  <input ng-model="league.color1">
  <input ng-model="league.color2">
</div>
```